# flexbox on android stock browser

Tags: android, css, flexbox

Ran into this problem, for the first time a couple of months ago, but can't remember how did i solve it.

Got a flex box that works fine everywhere except for android stock browser. Actually, it works fine horizontally, but refuses to go vertical on media query.

Here is the CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width:1023px) {
.newheadwrap {
flex-direction:column !important;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.newheadwrap {
-o-display:flex;
-webkit-display:flex;
-ms-display:flex;
-moz-display:flex;
display:-webkit-box;
display:-webkit-flex;
display:flex;  
flex-direction:row;
max-width:966px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I started off right with

```
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

Android stock browser takes older flex box syntax. Just forgot to make it !important

```
-webkit-box-orient: vertical !important;
```

got it going